# How to use Angular percentage pipe correctly in Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have the current from the component template:

```
<strong>{{data.value | percent:'1.0-2'}}</strong>
```

The example value is 1.0 from the database which mean I need to show 1%.
When using the percent pipe I'm getting 100% which is not correct.

Any idea how to combine decimal and percentage together? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving this.
One would be to divide `data.value` with 100. Which means

```
<strong>{{data.value / 100 | percent}}</strong>
```

will output `1%`.

Other one would be to just concat % at the end.

```
<strong>{{data.value}}%</strong>
```

Meaning if you pass 1.02 it will show `1.02%` if that is what you want